# How should I numerate my enum?

Tags: c++, enums

Normally, when I create an enum they each get incremented by one, see

```
enum
{
    A = 0,
    B,
    C,
    D
};
```

but after I looked into some source codes, I see people doing things like this

```
enum
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1 << 0,
    C = 1 << 1,
    D = 1 << 2
};
```

I understand what it means, but what exactly does this grant me? Are there any advantages? I only see that this makes it look unneccesary complex in my opinion.

Comment: Most likely items of that enum are used as some kind of flag that is mixed together by bitwise operations.

Comment: Note that if `A` is also a flag you shouldn't assign it with `0` so you can later test its representing bit (`0` has not bit of course).

Answer (score 7):

The second form creates flags for use in a bitmask. It's normally done to save space in objects that have several boolean conditions that control their behavior.

```
struct foo {
    std::uint32_t bitmask; // up to 32 different flags.
};

foo obj;
obj.bitmask = (B | D); // Sets the bits 0 and 2
```

Answer (score 5):

It creates a bit-mask type with unique bits set, so that the expression `B | C` is guaranteed not to be the same as `D`.

If you just want unique enum values that are not combined, the first version is totally ok. And you don't really have to use `= 0` for the first value. That will be the default anyway.